# pass values from jsp-jsf

Tags: jsf

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{Student.stuList}" var="stuList" bgcolor="#F1F1F1">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText style=""value="Stu Number" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText style="" value="#{stuList.stuNumber}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value=" Date"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{stuList.date}">
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="English"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{stuList.english}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Maths"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{stuList.maths}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Science"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{stuList.science}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>                    
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Student History"/>
                </f:facet>
             <h:form>
               <h:commandLink id = "historyBtn" value="Student History" action="#{stuBean.showHistory}">
                 <f:param name="stuNumber" value="#{stuBean.stuNumber}" />
               </h:commandLink></h:form>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

I've tried passing the parameters using the above code and I'm getting the following error:

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my R and D on web...cam to know that we dont need to pass input parameters on `<h:commandButton>` or `<h:commandLink>`

also I tried to refresh the list each time thus it worked..!!